# Grep uncertain list of lines with pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, fasta

Hi I have a similar situation with [Grep group of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353222/grep-group-of-lines), but slightly different.

I have a file in the format of:

```
> xxxx AB=AAA NNN xxxx CD=DDD xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
>xxxx AB=AAA JJJ xxxx CD=EEE xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
>xxxx AB=AAA NNN xxxx CD=FFF xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
>xxxx AB=EEE FFF xxxx CD=GGG xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

(each item starting with > does not necessarily contain same number of lines with xxx, xxx is a list of string with all capital letters, the only cue that the record of this item is completed is that the next line starts with >)

Firstly, I want to grep all items with AB = EEE FFF as a resultant file like below:

```
>xxxx AB=EEE FFF xxxx CD=GGG xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
>xxxx AB=EEE FFF xxxx CD=TTT xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
>xxxx AB=EEE FFF xxxx CD=EEE xxxxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

Then, I have a csv file with list of CD items, and I want to grep all these with CD=xxx as xxx is a line in csv file.

A sample of an item is:

```
>sp|P01023|A2MG_HUMAN Alpha-2-macroglobulin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=A2M PE=1 SV=3
MGKNKLLHPSLVLLLLVLLPTDASVSGKPQYMVLVPSLLHTETTEKGCVLLSYLNETVTV
SASLESVRGNRSLFTDLEAENDVLHCVAFAVPKSSSNEEVMFLTVQVKGPTQEFKKRTTV
MVKNEDSLVFVQTDKSIYKPGQTVKFR
```

AB in my example refers to OS here, and CD in my example refers to GN (so it's a single string containing capital letters AND/OR number

My csv file looks like (with ~1000 lines):

```
A2M
AIF1
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use `awk` and set the record separator to `>` . This makes awk treat your file as a set of multiline blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have much in the way of testable sample data but something like this might be a starting point:

```
awk -v s1='AB=EEE FFF' -v s2='CD' -v out='out.dat' '
    /^>/ {
        if ( ok = index($0,s1) )
            for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ )
                if ( index($i, s2"=")==1 )
                    print substr( $i, index($i,"=")+1 )
    }
    ok { print >out }
' in.dat |\
grep -Fx -f - in.csv >out.csv
```

use awk to process `in.csv`:

- look for lines starting `>` and if found:

  - set flag based on presence/absence of desired string s1 (flag will remain set until re-tested at next `>` line)
  - if s1 present, search for a field that starts with string s2 followed by `=`

    - if found, write section after `=` to stdout

      - (for efficiency, one could break out of the `for` here)
- if `ok` flag is set, copy the line to `out.dat`

awk's stdout is piped into grep.

use grep to search for fixed strings listed in awk's output that match an entire line of `in.csv`, and save results to `out.csv`